# Updating electron app manually

Tags: electron, auto-update, electron-builder

I was thinking this scenario

```
--> the user launch the app, the app is say you have updates
--> the user select yes or no to update or not to update
--> if select **no** the user don't update 
--> launch the app again the App say we have download your updates you 
    want to install now **YES** or **NO**

--> if select **yes** the app start installing the myApp-setup-v2.5.7
```

if you know how to make this with

1. electron-builder
2. electron-updater

The electron Updater is download the updates and close the app suddenly
I don't want that I want the user to have the control.

How I gona make this. ?

Comment: ok i gona doit give me 10 min